# JPA @ManyToMany does not seem to update join table with no CascadeType

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm a little confused by a result I am seeing in my code and am not sure if this is by JPA design, or if I have to dig a little further.

Given the following entity:

```
public class Provider implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "provider_contact", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Contact> contacts;
}
```

and the following code (occuring within a transaction):

```
/**
 * Updates the contact for the provider
 * @param providerId
 * @param contactDTO
 */
@Override
public Contact addContact(final long providerId, Contact contact){
    // first need to find the provider in the db
    Provider p = checkNotNull( providerRepository.findOne(providerId) );

    // need to save / update the contact if it already exists
    contactService.saveContact(contact);

    // add the contact to the provider
    if( p.getContacts() == null )
        p.setContacts(new ArrayList<Contact>());
    p.getContacts().add(contact);

    // return the contact
    return contact;
}
```

I expect to see both the contact persisted (based on the `contactService.saveContact()`) method, and the join table updated due to the fact that I've added the contact to the provider object.

However, the provider_contact join table is not being updated.

I did not think I needed a `CascadeType` of any sorts to do the update to the join table.  Am I mistaken?  Do I need to enforce `CascadeType.PERSIST`?  Or is there a problem in my code in the way I add the contact to my provider?

Comment: Can you show mapping at contact side?

Comment: Can you show your saveContact method?
And what TransactionScope your addContact method is?

Comment: Transaction scope is simply @Transactional (applied at the class level) ie. propagation enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions.  Turns out, there was a knock-on from another spot in the code (had to really trace through things to find it).  Ends up, I was looking in the wrong place in the code.

Another method was accidentally overwriting the `contacts` field (`List<Contact>`) to null.  Hence, upon the end of the transaction, the contact that was previous added was removed.

Answer (score 0):

You are only saving the `Contact` not the change made to the provider.
if you provider is mapped to your `Contact` then you can do it this way :

```
    @Override
public Contact addContact(final long providerId, Contact contact){
    // first need to find the provider in the db
    Provider p = checkNotNull( providerRepository.findOne(providerId) );

    // need to save / update the contact if it already exists
       // add the provider to the contact
    contact.addProvider(provider)

    //save the contact after adding a the provider
    Contact contact =  contactService.saveContact(contact);
        // return the contact
    return contact;
}
```

Or if it is not mapped you need to update the `Provider` by using a transactional method from the `ProviderService`:

```
@Override
public Contact addContact(final long providerId, Contact contact){
    // first need to find the provider in the db

    // need to save / update the contact if it already exists
    contactService.saveContact(contact);
     providerService.updateProvider(long provider, long contact);

    // return the contact
    return contact;
}
```

update provider from @ `ProviderService`

```
  @Override
  public Provider updateProvider(long providerId, long contact){
            // Get the provider from the service 
            Provider p =  providerService.get(providerId) ;
            //get contact from contact Servoce
                Contact contact = contactService.getContact(contact);

   if( p.getContacts() == null )
        p.setContacts(new ArrayList<Contact>());
    p.getContacts().add(contact);
        // update the provider
        return providerRepository.save(p) ;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand though.  If Provider is already a managed entity (which it is since it is retrieved through the `findOne()` method), any changes I make to the object should be automatically persisted at the end of the transaction.  I should not be required to manually call a save method on the managed provider object.

Comment: are you using Spring jpa Data? and findOne is from JpaRepository ?